# Exporting data from SQL to XML - NULL Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, null

I exported data from SQL Server to XML file like this :

```
USE Northwind;

SELECT * FROM Products FOR XML PATH;
```

For `NULL` value , it returned `xsi:nil="true"`.

For example: `<ProductName xsi:nil="true"/>`

Can I export without the `xsi:nil="true"` ?

But I do want to have tag name like : `<ProductName />` or `<ProductName></ProductName>`

Can someone tell me how to export like this?

Thanks.

Comment: hi,what is the database that u using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM Products
    FOR XML RAW('customer'), ROOT('customers')
```

ROOT clause in for XML statement creates root element for your XML document to create a well formed XML document , 
IF you want all the values in Elements you can add the Elements Clause in your FOR XML statement, which would be something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Products
FOR XML RAW('customer'), ROOT('customers'), Elements
```

Now if you add XSINIL clause at the end of it only then it will you the ELEMENTS will null values as , otherwise it will not return the element at all. Which will be something like this..

```
SELECT * FROM Products
FOR XML RAW('customer'), ROOT('customers'), Elements XSINIL
```